# ¿Obtener el name de un textbox y guardarlo en un arreglo MS Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

Cordial saludo compañeros, resulta que tengo un formulario, el cual crea labels y textbox automáticamente desde el load de el formulario , según la cantidad de registros que se encuentran en una consulta a la base de datos que tengo. usando este codigo:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class actividades
    Private Sub actividades_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        siguienteingeniero(contador)
        'variable para almacenar la conexion 
        Dim con As MySqlConnection
        con = conectar() 'se le asigna a la variable con la funcion de conexion 


        Dim sql As String = " SELECT nombre_actividad FROM actividades" 'variable donde se almacenara la consulta SQL
        Dim comando As New MySqlCommand(sql, con) ' ejecuta la consulta almacenada en SQL con la conexion CON
        comando.Connection = con
        Dim resultado As MySqlDataReader = comando.ExecuteReader() 'almacena en la variable resultado los datos obtenidos en la consulta



        'condicional para verificar 
        If resultado.HasRows Then

            'ciclo para recorrer los datos almacenados en el resultado 
            Do While resultado.Read()

                'agregamos los datos obtenidos 
                Dim lbs As New Label 'variable para crear labels a partir de su nombre
                Dim txtbox As New TextBox 'variable para crear textbox a partir de su nombre
                ReDim cajas(contartxtbox)
                'funcion para referirse al Textbox, y asignarle parametros 
                With txtbox
                    .Name = contartxtbox 'aqui se le agrega el nombre unico al textbox
                    .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(400, espacio) 'posicion donde va a quedar el textbox dentro del formulario
                    .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(70, 20) 'tamaño de la caja del textbox
                    .Text = "txt" & contartxtbox
                    .Parent = Me

                End With

                'funcion para referise al los labels y asignarle parametros
                With lbs
                    .Name = contarlb 'aqui se le asigna un nombre unico a cada label creado
                    .Text = resultado.Item("nombre_actividad") 'aqui se le asigna el texto contenido dentro del label apartir de la base de datos
                    .Parent = Me
                    .Location = New Point(50, espacio) 'posicion donde va a quedar el label dentro del formulario 
                    .Size = New Size(200, 50) 'tamaño de la caja del label
                End With



                'contadores 

                contarlb += 1
                contartxtbox += 1
                espacio += 50

            Loop
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("datos no encontrados")
        End If
        'btnconsultar.Enabled = False



        resultado.Close()
        con.Close()

End Sub
```

Funciona perfectamente, ahora lo que necesito es guardar en un arreglo, el name de cada textbox que se crea automaticamente segun la cantidad de registros de la bd intente con lo siguiente:

```
cajas(contartxtbox)=txtbox.name
```

Pero no guarda nada dentro del arreglo, lo que necesito puntualmente es en ese arreglo guardar el name de cada textbox para despues poder usarlo para unas operaciones, ¿como podria hacerlo?.

Comment: Mysql no tiene nada que ver con este problema. Visual studio 2017 tampoco ;). no esta como definiste cajas originalmente, pero en lugar de guardar el nombre del textbox, no deberias guardar el objeto textbox? asi despues podes hacer cosas con el.

Comment: No es mejor utilizar un DataGridView?

Comment: Solo necesito obtener el name de los textbox y guardarlos en un arreglo de tipo string, el objeto textbox esta definido en el codigo como dim txtbox as new textbox.

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar. donde esta definido cajas? porque si esta dentro del procedimiento, entonces no sirve porque esa variable se pierde al salir del mismo.

Comment: cajas esta definida en un modulo de variables publicas como tipo string

Comment: Podes agregar la definicion de cajas? no puede ser que pierdas los valores. y estas seguro que es el unico lugar donde lo tenes definido?

Comment: ASHHH.. tu redim esta perdiendo los valores anteriores. Agregale PRESERVE. ReDim PRESERVE cajas(contartxtbox)

Comment: @gbianchi efectivamente,el problema del OP es el `ReDim` probablemente. Y ya que hablamos de rendimiento, `ReDim` es una función malísima en cuanto rendimiento, yo no aconsejaría usarla nunca, pudiendo usar por ejemplo una `List<T>` :)

Comment: si o una collection o cualquier cosa que crezca sola..

Comment: Efectivamente ese era el problema, gracias, ya se soluciono. soy analista y desarrollador junior y tengo poca experiencia en este lenguaje, así que lo he ido explorando poco a poco, ya que una de mis labores actual es una aplicación desarrollada en este lenguaje, muchas gracias por la colaboración

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad, no necesitas almacenar los controles que has creado dinámicamente en ningun sitio. Puedes acceder a ellos haciendo uso de la colección `Controls` que posee cualquier contenedor, y el método `OfType` que devuelve solo los objetos que sean de un tipo. De la siguiente manera:

```
Private cajas = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
```

Si tuvieras otros TextBoxes aparte de los que generas dinámicamente, lo mejor es que a los que generas les pongas un prefijo exclusivo. Por ejemplo, si pones que siempre empiece con `dyn`, para encontrarles simplemente harías asi:

```
Private cajas = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().Where(Function(x) x.Name.StartsWith("dyn"))
```

Comment: Pero por una cuestion de velocidad.. no es mas facil guardar en una collection los controles que creaste? asi no tenes que andar rebuscando por muchos lugares, cosas que creaste vos ;)

Comment: @gbianchi El rendimiento de buscar en la colección `Controls` es practicamente idéntico a buscar en una colección propia (no lo he mirado, pero pondría la mano en el fuego).Y siempre podrías almacenarlo en una variable propia despues de añadirles. Pero creo que no es necesario guardarlo cuando ya lo tienes disponible de una manera automática :)